# c++ overloading constructor with new type/class and friend

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, friend

Is there anyway to use `friend` to overload an already declared struct's constructor with one that uses newly defined structure.  For example, in the simply example below, I want to overload `struct A` constructor with a one using `struct B`, **BUT without modifying A.h**.

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main() {
    B x(2);
    A y(B); 
};
```

A.h

```
struct A {
    float a;
    A(float);
};

A::A(float f)   { a=f; };
```

B.h

```
struct B {
    float b;
    B(float);
    B(A);
};

B::B(float f)   { b=f;   };
B::B(A s)       { b=s.a; };

A::A(B s){ a=s.b; };
// ^^^----obviously error since A(B) is not declared, 
// but how can I make this work without changing A.h?
```

I know I can solve the problem with the appropriate placement of `struct B;` and `A(B);` within the **A.h**.  I also figured out one method of using template, but it was not an elegant solution.  And it required modification of **A.h**.  For reasons I don't want to get in to here, I don't want to employ either of these technique.   I would like to overload A::A() constructor WITHOUT modifying **A.h** and more importantly, without assuming that placement of `#include "A.h"` is controllable.   I think this is what friend is for, but I don't know if/how to make it work with constructors.

Comment: Are you looking for [the conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add constructors (or other members) to a class. However, you can create a conversion operator in the other class involved:

```
class B {
   // ...
public:
    explicit operator A() const { /* build an A object and return it */ }
};
```

Comment: Do you think a conversion to `float` rather than `A` would be more appropriate, so that OP's example could use the constructor `A(float);`?

Comment: @AndyG: The conversion operator can do whatever it needs to constructor the `A` object including building an `A` using the constructor from `float` followed by some mutations. If a non-`explicit` constructor is desired, converting to `A` directly also reduces the number of conversions in some conversion sequences.

Comment: I've never seen this conversion operator, and I'm not sure how it differs functionally from a constructor, but as I'm testing it, it seems works exactly as I need it to and conforms to my constraints.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload something that doesn't exist. You can't define non existing member functions either. But you can write a simple function to do the work for you:

```
A fromB(const B& s) { return A(s.b); }
```

If you are allowed to modify `B`, you can give it a conversion operator:

```
struct B {
    explicit operator A() const { return A(b); }

    // as before
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't a conversion operator do the same?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, that could be an option.

Comment: In terms of meeting my desired functionality and elegance, the conversion operator is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a control over `B` and want to define a way how to make `A` from `B` you can define a so called conversion operator:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(float val) : _val(val) {};
    float _val;
};

struct B{
    operator A(){ // how to make A from B.
        return A(2);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a = b;
    cout << a._val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It basically defines a cast operator.